# Monitoring kubernetes services or deployment through Prometheus

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, kubernetes-health-check

I have a k8s cluster v1.8. I was trying to setup prometheus on my cluster so basically am trying to monitor services and deployment. But with the below config-map i am not able to view any of my services or deployments.

```html
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: prometheus
data:
  prometheus.yml: |-
    global:
      scrape_interval: 15s
   
    scrape_configs:
    - job_name: 'kubernetes-apiservers'

      kubernetes_sd_configs:
      - role: endpoints

      # Default to scraping over https. If required, just disable this or change to
      # `http`.
      scheme: https

      # This TLS & bearer token file config is used to connect to the actual scrape
      # endpoints for cluster components. This is separate to discovery auth
      # configuration because discovery & scraping are two separate concerns in
      # Prometheus. The discovery auth config is automatic if Prometheus runs inside
      # the cluster. Otherwise, more config options have to be provided within the
      # <kubernetes_sd_config>.
      tls_config:
        ca_file: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/ca.crt
        # If your node certificates are self-signed or use a different CA to the
        # master CA, then disable certificate verification below. Note that
        # certificate verification is an integral part of a secure infrastructure
        # so this should only be disabled in a controlled environment. You can
        # disable certificate verification by uncommenting the line below.
        #
        # insecure_skip_verify: true
      bearer_token_file: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token

      # Keep only the default/kubernetes service endpoints for the https port. This
      # will add targets for each API server which Kubernetes adds an endpoint to
      # the default/kubernetes service.
      relabel_configs:
      - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_namespace, __meta_kubernetes_service_name, __meta_kubernetes_endpoint_port_name]
        action: keep
        regex: default;kubernetes;https

    # Scrape config for nodes (kubelet).
    #
    # Rather than connecting directly to the node, the scrape is proxied though the
    # Kubernetes apiserver.  This means it will work if Prometheus is running out of
    # cluster, or can't connect to nodes for some other reason (e.g. because of
    # firewalling).
    - job_name: 'kubernetes-nodes'

      # Default to scraping over https. If required, just disable this or change to
      # `http`.
      scheme: https

      # This TLS & bearer token file config is used to connect to the actual scrape
      # endpoints for cluster components. This is separate to discovery auth
      # configuration because discovery & scraping are two separate concerns in
      # Prometheus. The discovery auth config is automatic if Prometheus runs inside
      # the cluster. Otherwise, more config options have to be provided within the
      # <kubernetes_sd_config>.
      tls_config:
        ca_file: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/ca.crt
      bearer_token_file: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token

      kubernetes_sd_configs:
      - role: node

      relabel_configs:
      - action: labelmap
        regex: __meta_kubernetes_node_label_(.+)
      - target_label: __address__
        replacement: kubernetes.default.svc:443
      - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_node_name]
        regex: (.+)
        target_label: __metrics_path__
        replacement: /api/v1/nodes/${1}/proxy/metrics

    # Scrape config for Kubelet cAdvisor.
    #
    # This is required for Kubernetes 1.7.3 and later, where cAdvisor metrics
    # (those whose names begin with 'container_') have been removed from the
    # Kubelet metrics endpoint.  This job scrapes the cAdvisor endpoint to
    # retrieve those metrics.
    #
    # In Kubernetes 1.7.0-1.7.2, these metrics are only exposed on the cAdvisor
    # HTTP endpoint; use "replacement: /api/v1/nodes/${1}:4194/proxy/metrics"
    # in that case (and ensure cAdvisor's HTTP server hasn't been disabled with
    # the --cadvisor-port=0 Kubelet flag).
    #
    # This job is not necessary and should be removed in Kubernetes 1.6 and
    # earlier versions, or it will cause the metrics to be scraped twice.
    - job_name: 'kubernetes-cadvisor'

      # Default to scraping over https. If required, just disable this or change to
      # `http`.
      scheme: https

      # This TLS & bearer token file config is used to connect to the actual scrape
      # endpoints for cluster components. This is separate to discovery auth
      # configuration because discovery & scraping are two separate concerns in
      # Prometheus. The discovery auth config is automatic if Prometheus runs inside
      # the cluster. Otherwise, more config options have to be provided within the
      # <kubernetes_sd_config>.
      tls_config:
        ca_file: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/ca.crt
      bearer_token_file: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token

      kubernetes_sd_configs:
      - role: node

      relabel_configs:
      - action: labelmap
        regex: __meta_kubernetes_node_label_(.+)
      - target_label: __address__
        replacement: kubernetes.default.svc:443
      - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_node_name]
        regex: (.+)
        target_label: __metrics_path__
        replacement: /api/v1/nodes/${1}/proxy/metrics/cadvisor

    # Scrape config for service endpoints.
    #
    # The relabeling allows the actual service scrape endpoint to be configured
    # via the following annotations:
    #
    # * `prometheus.io/scrape`: Only scrape services that have a value of `true`
    # * `prometheus.io/scheme`: If the metrics endpoint is secured then you will need
    # to set this to `https` & most likely set the `tls_config` of the scrape config.
    # * `prometheus.io/path`: If the metrics path is not `/metrics` override this.
    # * `prometheus.io/port`: If the metrics are exposed on a different port to the
    # service then set this appropriately.
    - job_name: 'kubernetes-service-endpoints'

      kubernetes_sd_configs:
      - role: endpoints

      relabel_configs:
      - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_service_annotation_prometheus_io_scrape]
        action: keep
        regex: true
      - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_service_annotation_prometheus_io_scheme]
        action: replace
        target_label: __scheme__
        regex: (https?)
      - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_service_annotation_prometheus_io_path]
        action: replace
        target_label: __metrics_path__
        regex: (.+)
      - source_labels: [__address__, __meta_kubernetes_service_annotation_prometheus_io_port]
        action: replace
        target_label: __address__
        regex: ([^:]+)(?::\d+)?;(\d+)
        replacement: $1:$2
      - action: labelmap
        regex: __meta_kubernetes_service_label_(.+)
      - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_namespace]
        action: replace
        target_label: kubernetes_namespace
      - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_service_name]
        action: replace
        target_label: kubernetes_name

    # Example scrape config for probing services via the Blackbox Exporter.
    #
    # The relabeling allows the actual service scrape endpoint to be configured
    # via the following annotations:
    #
    # * `prometheus.io/probe`: Only probe services that have a value of `true`
    - job_name: 'kubernetes-services'

      metrics_path: /probe
  
      kubernetes_sd_configs:
      - role: service

      relabel_configs:
      - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_service_annotation_prometheus_io_probe]
        action: keep
        regex: true
      - source_labels: [__address__]
        target_label: __param_target
      - target_label: __address__
        replacement: blackbox-exporter.example.com:9115
      - source_labels: [__param_target]
        target_label: instance
      - action: labelmap
        regex: __meta_kubernetes_service_label_(.+)
      - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_namespace]
        target_label: kubernetes_namespace
      - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_service_name]
        target_label: kubernetes_name

    # Example scrape config for probing ingresses via the Blackbox Exporter.
    #
    # The relabeling allows the actual ingress scrape endpoint to be configured
    # via the following annotations:
    #
    # * `prometheus.io/probe`: Only probe services that have a value of `true`
   
    # Example scrape config for pods
    #
    # The relabeling allows the actual pod scrape endpoint to be configured via the
    # following annotations:
    #
    # * `prometheus.io/scrape`: Only scrape pods that have a value of `true`
    # * `prometheus.io/path`: If the metrics path is not `/metrics` override this.
    # * `prometheus.io/port`: Scrape the pod on the indicated port instead of the
    # pod's declared ports (default is a port-free target if none are declared).
    - job_name: 'kubernetes-pods'

      kubernetes_sd_configs:
      - role: pod

      relabel_configs:
      - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_pod_annotation_prometheus_io_scrape]
        action: keep
        regex: true
      - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_pod_annotation_prometheus_io_path]
        action: replace
        target_label: __metrics_path__
        regex: (.+)
      - source_labels: [__address__, __meta_kubernetes_pod_annotation_prometheus_io_port]
        action: replace
        regex: ([^:]+)(?::\d+)?;(\d+)
        replacement: $1:$2
        target_label: __address__
      - action: labelmap
        regex: __meta_kubernetes_pod_label_(.+)
      - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_namespace]
        action: replace
        target_label: kubernetes_namespace
      - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_pod_name]
        action: replace
        target_label: kubernetes_pod_name
```

My target page output looks like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q6F6O.png .
What i want from Prometheus is to give k8s service or deployment metrics data also.
Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Your scrape configs don't have any section for deployments, you will have to write it out.

Comment: Ok i will add that up. but it's not even given any data about running services in my cluster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As said in the docs for the configuration job called 'kubernetes-pods' that you pasted above:

> `prometheus.io/scrape`: Only scrape pods that have a value of `true`

So your pods need to have that annotation set to true in order for Prometheus to scrape the configured path. Note that you can configure the path and port where your applications are exposing metrics using annotations like `prometheus.io/path` and `prometheus.io/port`.

Comment: Yeah i have changed that.It worked.Thanks for the comment.Now my services are visible but i was wondering how it will give me CPU, memory usage, etc information.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Prometheus only scrapes whatever metrics are exposed on your application's endpoint. It doesn't know which metrics are exposed. So it's up to your application to expose the metrics that you think are interesting. How to do that? It will depend on many things, like the language of the application and so on. There are libraries that would help you with that like http://micrometer.io/

Comment: any news @AbhayDwivedi?